# Python3 streaming string replacement

Tags: python, csv, stringio

I have a python3 "file-like object" whose `read()` method returns a string - it comes from either an opened file or an object streamed from `s3` using `boto3`.

I want to sanitize the stream before passing it to `csv.DictReader`, in particular because that module barfs on `NUL` characters on the input.

The CSV files I'm processing may be large, so I want to do this "streaming", not reading the entire file/object into memory.

How do I wrap the input object so that I can clean up every string returned from `read()` with a call like: `.replace('\x00', '{NUL}')`?

I think that the `io` library is where to look, but I couldn't find something that obviously did what I want - to be able to intercept and transform every call to `.read()` on the underlying file-like object and pass the wrapper to `csv`, without reading the whole thing at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple generator function that fixes the data before passing it on to `csv.reader`:

```
import io
import csv


def denull(line_gen):
    for line in line_gen:
        yield line.replace('\x00', '{NUL}')


data = io.StringIO("""
hello;world
asdf;h\x00pla
""".strip())

for row in csv.reader(denull(data), delimiter=";"):
    print(row)
```

prints out

```
['hello', 'world']
['asdf', 'h{NUL}pla']
```

Comment: I get `object is not iterable` - I guess `csv.DictReader` needs an `Iterable[str]` object - how do I accomplish that?

Comment: Ah yeah, just tried this out with `csv`. Just a sec, this becomes even easier :)